# PHP's array_flip causes undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays

This is my original array:

`Array ( [0] => pid [1] => pname [2] => paddress [3] => pphone)`

After using `array_flip`, it becomes this, which is how I want it:

`Array ( [pid] => 0 [pname] => 1 [paddress] => 2 [pphone] => 3)`

However, I can't seem to use the array anymore. When I try to loop through each item, I get undefined offset.

Comment: How do you loop through? Post the code snippet

Comment: how are you looping through it?  `foreach($array as $key => $value)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you were using a for loop before you flipped the array it will no longer work because the array becomes an associative array. You can use a `foreach($array as $k => $v )` loop and it should work.

for loops only work with an array that is indexed numerically.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
  echo $array[$i];
}
```

foreach is used for associative arrays.

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
  echo $k.'=>'.$v;
}
```

**Edit:** you can use a foreach array with a numerically indexed array as well.

Answer (score 0):

use foreach to loop the array

```
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "key=$key"."</br>";
    echo "value=$value";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you are trying to access it by a string-key then it will throw the error 'undefined offset x'.

You need to ensure that if you are running it through a loop then you need to specify the key and value:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    // do stuff
}
```

Or if you prefer you can get the values/keys without doing a loop, which is probably more efficient way of doing it:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

$x = array_flip($array);
$flipped_keys = array_keys($x);
$flipped_values = array_values($x);
echo $x[$flipped_keys[0]];
```

Hopefully this will help